# Improving size and efficiency of repeated formulas in Excel

Tags: excel

I often find myself using repeated formulas in my Excel work.  For example, we compare datasets by using formulas that use MATCH and INDIRECT to look up a value in one sheet and compare it to the value of another and list the discrepancies.  It works well, but it's slow.  There are something like 50,000 rows and 60 columns, so the number of calculations gets pretty large.  I've tried using LAMBDA in a named function, just on the chance that would be more internally efficient.  It reduced the file size by a few percent, but otherwise didn't really help.

Here's an example formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($D4)),
LET(X,
    XLOOKUP($D4,
        INDIRECT(LET(Y, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Comparison!$E$3,Vantage!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""),"Vantage!"&Y&":"&Y)),
        INDIRECT(LET(Y, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Comparison!H$3,Vantage!$1:$1,0),4),"1",""),"Vantage!"&Y&":"&Y)))&"",
    IF(ISERROR(X),"SRNotFound",X)),
"")
```

I don't think the formula itself is very relevant, but there it is.  The question is, what methods are there, if any, to reduce both file size and calculation load when a particular formula like that is used over and over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of INDIRECT which is slow and Volatile we can use INDEX.

Also the last check in unneeded with XLOOKUP as it has a return when the match is not found.

```
=IF(
    $D4<>"",
    XLOOKUP(
        D4,
        INDEX(Vantage!$1:$1040000,0,MATCH(Comparison!$E$3,Vantage!$1:$1,0)),
        INDEX(Vantage!$1:$1040000,0,MATCH(Comparison!H$3,Vantage!$1:$1,0)),
        "SRNotFound")
   ,"")
```

This should be a lot quicker as well as not need to recalc every time something was changed anywhere in Excel.

Comment: Thank you.  This is certainly better than what I had.